# Como converter JSON em Objeto e encontrar um id (Sem Array) - JAVA

Tags: java, json

Estou com um Json que não contem um array e preciso pegar uma informação deste Json.
Segue o JSON

```
 {"_status":"sucesso","_mensagem":"Impressão em processamento","_dados":{"situacao":"PROCESSANDO","protocolo":"BkVglXYWQ"}}
```

O que tentei fazer até agora

```
JsonReader jsonReader = Json.createReader(new StringReader(jsonProtocolo));
    JsonObject jsonObject = jsonReader.readObject();
    JsonObject attributeDados = jsonObject.getJsonObject("_dados");
    JsonArray jsonArray = attributeDados.getJsonArray("_sucesso");

    String numeroProtocolo = jsonArray.getJsonObject(0).getString("protocolo");

    System.out.println("NUMERO PROTOCOLO: " + numeroProtocolo);
```

Porém recebo nullPointer na linha   String numeroProtocolo = jsonArray.getJsonObject(0).getString("protocolo");
Também tentei assim

```
 JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(jsonProtocolo);
    String numeroProtocolo = obj.getString("protocolo");

    System.out.println("NUMERO PROTOCOLO: " + numeroProtocolo);
```

Porém recebo o erro: JSONObject["protocolo"] not found

Comment: talvez esse link possa te ajudar:
http://theoryapp.com/parse-json-in-java/

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta amigo, tentei assim mais sem sucesso, vou atualizar a pergunta com o código que tentei

Comment: Consegui resolver assim
 JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(jsonProtocolo);
        String numeroProtocolo = obj.getJSONObject("_dados").getString("protocolo");

Comment: sim, estava escrevendo de fazer assim como resposta =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema assim

```
 JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(jsonProtocolo);
    String numeroProtocolo = obj.getJSONObject("_dados").getString("protocolo");
```

Se alguém precisar esta ai;

Answer (score 4):

O problema está aqui:

```
String numeroProtocolo = jsonArray.getJsonObject(0).getString("protocolo");
```

`_dados` é um objeto e não um array, tente isso:

```
String numeroProtocolo = jsonObject.getJSONObject("_dados").getString("protocolo");
```

Objetos JSON estão rodeados por `{}`, enquanto Arrays são rodeadas por `[]`.

Answer (score 1):

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(jsonProtocolo);
JSONObject dados = obj.getJSONObject("_dados");
String numeroProtocolo = dados.getString("protocolo");
```