# Java - Pegar o valor de um elemento específico de um JSON

Tags: java, json

Estou utilizando a API exchangerate (https://www.exchangerate-api.com) para pegar as cotações de moeda do dia.

Utilizando o código abaixo eu pego um JsonObject contendo os "rates":

```
   private JsonObject getExchangesRate() throws JsonIOException, JsonSyntaxException, IOException {

    // Setting URL
    String url_str = "https://v3.exchangerate-api.com/bulk/f75b7f1b080c9060121e6754/BRL";

    // Making Request
    URL url = new URL(url_str);
    HttpURLConnection request = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    request.connect();

    // Convert to JSON
    JsonParser jp = new JsonParser();
    JsonElement root = jp.parse(new InputStreamReader((InputStream) request.getContent()));
    JsonObject jsonobj = root.getAsJsonObject();

    // Accessing object
    return jsonobj;

}
```

Teoricamente, é para ele vir neste formato:

```
{
   "result": "success",
   "from": "USD",
   "rates": {
      "AUD": ((AUD in terms of USD)),
      "BGN": 1.8096,
      "BRL": 3.1143,
      "...": 1.3113,
      "...": 7.473, etc. etc.
   }
}
```

Estou tentando pegar os valores dentro da chave "rates" e armazenar os valores de USD, EUR e GBP.

Mas não estou conseguindo. Dei uma lida de como funciona JSON em Java mas mesmo assim não estou conseguindo fazer o que quero.

```
JsonObject resultadoJSON = getExchangesRate();      

    JsonElement rates = resultadoJSON.get("rates");
    double ValorUSD = (double) rates.get("USD"); //Sei que não é assim, mas é o que to tentando fazer
    double ValorEUR = (double) rates.get("EUR"); //Sei que não é assim, mas é o que to tentando fazer
```

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como converter JSON em Objeto e encontrar um id (Sem Array) - JAVA](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/308726/como-converter-json-em-objeto-e-encontrar-um-id-sem-array-java)

Comment: Verifique também [Como converter JSON em Objeto e encontrar um id - JAVA](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/308219/como-converter-json-em-objeto-e-encontrar-um-id-java).

Answer (score 1):

Você pode adicionar um cast no objeto rates como um JsonObject e logo após, pegar os respectivos valores das moedas convertidos como JsonElement:

```
public JsonElement getExchangesRate() throws JsonIOException, JsonSyntaxException, IOException {

        // Setting URL
        String url_str = "https://v3.exchangerate-api.com/bulk/f75b7f1b080c9060121e6754/BRL";

        // Making Request
        URL url = new URL(url_str);
        HttpURLConnection request = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        request.connect();

        // Convert to JSON
        JsonParser jp = new JsonParser();
        JsonElement root = jp.parse(new InputStreamReader((InputStream) request.getContent()));
        JsonObject jsonobj = root.getAsJsonObject();
        JsonObject rates = (JsonObject) jsonobj.get("rates");



        // Accessing element
        return rates.get("USD");

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver da seguinte maneira:

```
JsonObject JSONResult = getExchangesRate(); 
JsonObject rates =  JSONResult.getAsJsonObject("rates");

Double ValorUSD = 1 / rates.get("USD").getAsDouble(); 
Double ValorEUR = 1 / rates.get("EUR").getAsDouble();
Double ValorGBP = 1 / rates.get("GBP").getAsDouble();   //English Pounds
```

O problema era que o pacote que estava utilizando é o GSON (conforme especificado no site da API) e não o JSON normal do Java. Por isso do jeito comum não estava conseguindo.